# RoutingProvider.GetRoute(...) is returning null, what is wrong and ist there a GMapProvider which does not need a API Key?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gmap.net

vs express 2015 c# gmap.net.windows by jurgen de leon... 1.9.9.9

simple code sample:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PointLatLng pos1 = new PointLatLng(-33.9747, -53.5389);
        PointLatLng pos2 = new PointLatLng(-33.8974, -53.5085);

        mapctl.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
        mapctl.MapProvider = GMapProviders.OpenStreetMap;
        mapctl.MinZoom = 0;
        mapctl.MaxZoom = 20;
        mapctl.Zoom = 10;

        /*-null->*/ MapRoute path = mapctl.RoutingProvider.GetRoute(pos1, pos2, false, false, 10);
                    GMapRoute route = new GMapRoute(path.Points, "My route");
                    GMapOverlay ovlRoutes = new GMapOverlay("myRoutes");
                    ovlRoutes.Routes.Add(route);
                    mapctl.Overlays.Add(ovlRoutes);
                    mapctl.ZoomAndCenterRoute(route); 
        }
```

what is wrong?
and ist there a GMapProvider which does not need a API Key?

i want to show a route from a to b, following the road as you know it ...

For private education only!
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: hy sorry my english ist not so good...
i open a new project
then i add the nuget's
   entity framework by microsoft
   gmap.net.windows by jurgen...
finally i insert a GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl on the form1 as mapctl
the rest of the code ist published...
best regards

Comment: do not know the reason, but:
with other coordinates this sample works. from mainroad to mainroad. 
a) not possible to avoid highways (true) --> path = null
b) not possible in walking mode (true) --> path = null
c) from highway to a point on a side road --> path to wrong destination
hmm